# Drag and drop Chrome downloads like any other OS X file?

Tags: macos, finder, google-chrome, file, chrome-extensions

When I've downloaded a file in Chrome for OS X, it sits in a little bar at the bottom of the screen.

Sometimes I want to drag and drop that file directly into a Chrome tab (for example, to upload it somewhere.)

Some websites allow this.

Other websites, however, won't allow this. They only accept files from Finder, not ones dragged directly from the downloads bar.

How can I get Chrome and/or OS X to treat these files from the downloads bar as normal Finder files, so that websites will be unable to differentiate?

I realize that I could, (and I in fact do), just locate the file in Finder and drag it from there. However, I do this often and it would save me time if I could just drag it directly from Chrome itself.

Comment: Can you specify a web page? Every page I try is working with drag & drop in Chrome (Version 50)

Comment: @YoshiBotX When I try to upload images to answers or questions on Stack Exchange. Also, http://web.airdroid.com If these work for you, which OS X version do you have?

Comment: Using OS X El Capitan 10.11.4 & Chrome 50 it does not work with simple drag & drop, but when holding the alt/option key.

Comment: @YoshiBotX Groovy! Works on Yosemite too! You can definitely post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holding the <kbd>alt</kbd> or <kbd>option</kbd> key while doing the Drag & Drop action works.

*I think since Chrome also handles webpages as links (html) to open them in the browser, it does the same for downloaded files. If you simply hold <kbd>alt</kbd> while clicking a link it also downloads the file. So I assume Chrome treats the downloaded "link" as a 'file' when holding that key.*

You could also use <kbd>cmd</kbd> + Click to *"Show In Finder"*